# This proof of the Pigeonhole principle has a real (and not integer) number equal to a variable that needs to be an integer

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

"Proof" of the Pigeonhole principle:

Suppose we have $n$ elements partitioned into $m$ subsets.  By contradiction, suppose that no subset contains more than $\lceil n/m \rceil -1$  elements.  Then the total number of elements is at most $$m(\lceil \frac nm \rceil -1) < m(( \frac nm +1)-1)=n$$

where $\lceil \ \rceil$ is the ceiling function.

The easiest way of thinking about it for me is that the equality holds because $\lceil n/m \rceil $ is always less than $n/m+1$.

But in the event that $(n/m)$ is not an integer, $(n/m+1)$ is also not an integer.

So on the right hand side we have something that is potentially not an integer being equal to $n$. But $n$ is a number of elements, so it has to be an integer, no? Is this proof not problematic for this reason?

Comment: There is no problem. While $n/m$ might not be an integer, $m(n/m)$ definitely is.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Ahhh I see, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is, at worst, inelegant to use a non-integer in a discrete math proof.  If one wanted to avoid it (and I'm not saying you have to), one might write something like

> Suppose we have $n$ elements partitioned into $m$ subsets. Let $k,r$ be positive integers such that $n=km+r$ with $1\leq r\leq m$.  Since $n>km$, it must be at at least one of the subsets contains more than $k$ elements.

And then either apply the definition or a lemma to indicate that $k=\lceil{m\over n}\rceil-1$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the help!